# BeautifulSoup doesn't find all spans or children

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access the sequence on this webpage:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/EGW15053.1?report=fasta

The sequence is stored under the div class="seq gbff". Each line is stored under

```
<span class='ff_line' id='gi_344258949_1"> *line 1 of sequence* </span>
```

When I try to search for the spans containing the sequence, beautiful soup returns `None`. Same problem when I try to look at the children or content of the `div` above the `spans`.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Create a variable with the url
url = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/EGW15053.1?report=fasta'

# Use requests to get the contents
r = requests.get(url)

# Get the text of the contents
html_content = r.text

# Convert the html content into a beautiful soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')


div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class', 'seq gbff'})
for each in div.children:
    print(each)
soup.find_all('span', aatrs={'class', 'ff_line'})
```

Neither method works and I'd greatly appreciate any help :D

Answer (score 2):

This page uses JavaScript to load data

With `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox I found this url and there are all `<span>`

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id=344258949&db=protein&report=fasta&extrafeat=0&fmt_mask=0&retmode=html&withmarkup=on&tool=portal&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=1000000

Now hard part. You have to find this url in HTML because different pages will use different arguments in url. Or you have to compare few urls and find schema so you could generate this url manually.

---

**EDIT:** if in url you change `retmode=html` to `retmode=xml` then you get it as `XML`. If you use `retmode=text` then you get it as text without `HTML` tags. `retmode=json` doesn't works.

Comment: See new text "hard part"

Comment: see `retmode=text` in answer

Comment: That's actually easy for me. 
div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class', 'seq gbff'}) contains the unique value for each page I want to access, just have to replace the id in each url.

Comment: I checked url need only three arguments to get data `id=344258949&report=fasta&retmode=text`